# How can I access a SQL file while using python?

Tags: python, sql, database

Right now I'm using Microsoft SQL Community to start a database, but for some reason I can't command the server to do something that I want, is there any to use the library **sqlite3** or **pyodc** to print a value that I want on the console?

### PYTHON:

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect("REPLICATED_STORAGE.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql_file = open("Template.sql")
sql_as_string = sql_file.read()
cursor.executescript(sql_as_string)

for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM FRUITS"):
    print(row)
```

## SQL:

```sql
USE [REPLICATED_STORAGE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FRUITS](
    [COLOR] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TYPE] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [NAME] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [WEIGHT] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: if you are connecting to sql server , why are you suing sqlite interface?

Comment: If the table was just created, then it won't have any data to print...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3` talks to [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) databases.

If you want to talk to a Microsoft SQL Server, [Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#getting-started) using [`pyodbc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15). Follow the [instructions to connect and run queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [pyodbc documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki). To execute queries from a file, read the contents of the file and run it like any other query.

Note that [`executescript`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executescript) is specific to sqlite3. Use [`execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14).